# Build Qt project from AppVeyor

Tags: windows, qt, continuous-integration, appveyor

Is it possible to use [AppVeyor](http://www.appveyor.com/) as a Windows Qt continuous integration service?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Qt* is preinstalled on all configurations. See http://www.appveyor.com/docs/installed-software#qt

Here is an example script for *appveyor.yml* :

```
install:
  - set QTDIR=C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32
  - set PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin;C:\MinGW\bin
build_script:
  - qmake QtTest.pro
  - mingw32-make
```

Supported compiler environments are `mingw492_32`, `msvc2013` and `msvc2013_64`.

Comment: Note that Qt libraries are now pre-installed on "unstable". See http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/suggestions/419-qt-libraries and a build file using it at https://github.com/Phonations/Joker/blob/master/appveyor.yml

Comment: In fact I'm the main Joker developer! I head from the unstable option afterward

Comment: The appveyor developer has been very reactive through its forum! That is a nice service like travis-ci :-)

Comment: I just update my script since qt is available for all configuration.

Comment: check out the list of installed Qt versions [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#qt)

Comment: Instead of

set PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin;C:\MinGW\bin

I had to use

set PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin

to use the gcc compiler that comes with Qt. Otherwise I got a "procedure entry point" error regarding qt5core.dll

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Qt is now available for all configurations - http://www.appveyor.com/docs/installed-software#qt

Comment: Now the only problem is how to get it Qt5 running on Travis as well.

Comment: I do it long before appveyor. Checkout my project: https://github.com/Phonations/joker

Comment: Nice scripting. I guess I stick to that solution too, even though most people want it to run on container based infra, which seems impossible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116370/qt-apt-package-and-list-for-travis-ci