# How to fix QtMsBuild errors when building VS2019 Qt 5.15.2 project on AppVeyor?

Tags: c++, qt, appveyor

I am trying to set up continuous integration for my project using appveyor, but I keep getting errors related to QtMsBuild when building the project on appveyor. Here is the output of the build:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  QtMsBuild: could not locate qt.targets, qt.props; project may not build correctly.
  AutoAwayMonitorThread.cpp
  ifunctions.cpp
C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAwayMonitorThread.cpp(3,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/QDebug': No such file or directory [C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAway.vcxproj]
  SettingsDialog.cpp
C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAwayMonitorThread.h(5,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/QThread': No such file or directory (compiling source file ifunctions.cpp) [C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAway.vcxproj]
C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\SettingsDialog.h(3,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWidgets/QDialog': No such file or directory (compiling source file SettingsDialog.cpp) [C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAway.vcxproj]
  AutoAway.cpp
C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAwayMonitorThread.h(5,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/QThread': No such file or directory (compiling source file AutoAway.cpp) [C:\projects\autoaway\AutoAway\AutoAway.vcxproj]
```

Here is my appveyor configuration file:

https://github.com/poqdavid/AutoAway/blob/master/appveyor.yml

I have installed Qt 5.15.2 and Qt VS Tools on my local machine and the project builds fine there.

I have followed the instructions from https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/ and [Build Qt project from AppVeyor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586006/build-qt-project-from-appveyor) to set up my appveyor.yml file and environment variables.

I have also searched for similar issues on stackoverflow and other forums, but none of the solutions worked for me.

How can I fix these errors and build my project successfully on appveyor?